# Java Counting occurrences in a List and removing addition/duplicates from the structure while updating the word count

Tags: java

I currently have the words reading from a text file into a String ArrayList. My assignment asked me to not use any HashMaps or HashSets, anything of that nature. While counting the occurrences of a word I also have to remove any additionals(, . :  [] ; = -) and duplicates of the same word. Just currently having trouble with how to remove the additionals and removing duplicates any help is appreciated (Beginner at Java). Unable to use splits.

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
{
    //Create input Scanner
    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("Assignment1BData.txt");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(file);

    //Create the ArrayList
    ArrayList<String> wordCount = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Integer> numCount = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    //Read through the file and find the words from text
    while(input.hasNext())
    {
        String word = input.next();

        //Create index to look through lines of text
        if(wordCount.contains(word))
        {
            int index = numCount.indexOf(word);
            numCount.set(index, numCount.get(index) + 1);
        }
        else
        {
            wordCount.add(word);
            numCount.add(1);
        }
    }
    input.close();
    file.close();

    //Print output in for loop
    for(int i = 0; i < wordCount.size(); i++)
    {
        System.out.println(wordCount.get(i) + " = " + numCount.get(i));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

indexOf(Object o) method on the ArrayList should solve the problem of duplicates. Before you go on to add the string to the ArrayList simply call this method if that string already exists in the ArrayList it returns the index otherwise it returns -1. Just keep adding the string read from the text file to ArrayList as long as the indexOf method returns -1 otherwise simply ignore(since it already exists).

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like: `newList = removeDuplicates(YourList)` So that the duplicates would get removed and you get a new list...

Got it here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-remove-duplicates-from-arraylist-in-java/

Answer (score 0):

Try this, for replacng special symbols before doing lookup and doing the count .

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WordCounter {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         //Create input Scanner
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("/tmp/Assignment1BData.txt");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(file);

        //Create the ArrayList
        ArrayList<String> wordCount = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<Integer> numCount = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        //Read through the file and find the words from text
        while(input.hasNextLine())
        {
            String word = input.nextLine();
            //Replace all characters 
            word = word.replaceAll("[,.:;=-\\[\\]]", ""); 

            //Create index to look through lines of text
            if(wordCount.contains(word))
            {
                int index = wordCount.indexOf(word);
                numCount.set(index, numCount.get(index) + 1);
            }
            else
            {
                wordCount.add(word);
                numCount.add(1);
            }
        }
        input.close();
        file.close();

        //Print output in for loop
        for(int i = 0; i < wordCount.size(); i++)
        {
            System.out.println(wordCount.get(i) + " = " + numCount.get(i));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Sample input file : testing
hello
test-tesing
tes,ting
hello.                    Sample output : testing = 2
hello = 2
testtesing = 1

Answer (score 0):

You can try by creating a list with unique elements using Stream API as,

```
List<Integer> listWithDuplicates = Lists.newArrayList(5, 0, 3, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0);
    List<Integer> listWithoutDuplicates = listWithDuplicates.stream()
     .distinct()
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Then iterate over the original array/list (listWithDuplicates ) and get it compared with listWithoutDuplicates and count for the match.